# how to run multiple instances of a local zimserver in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I downloaded offline zim archives of websites such as `wikipedia.com`, `stackoverflow.com`, `unix.stackexchange.com` etc. and serve them via below script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import subprocess
import sys
import threading 
from zimply import ZIMServer
ZIMServer("/home/user/zim/wikipedia_en_all_novid_2018-05.zim", index_file="/home/user/zim/wikipedia_en_all_novid_2018-05.idx", port=8790, encoding="utf-8")
```

it works well but when I add another line

```
 ZIMServer("/home/user/zim/math.stackexchange.com_eng_all_2018-08.zim",  index_file="/home/user/zim/math.stackexchange.com_eng_all_2018-08.idx", port=7890, encoding="utf-8")
```

it doesn't load the second `ZIMServer`. I think it's a python multithreading issue. How can I run both of them in the single script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [multiprocessing — Process-based parallelism](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html), plus port incrementation.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

import os
import subprocess
import sys
import threading
from zimply import ZIMServer

def f(port, file, idx):
    ZIMServer(file, index_file=idx, port=port, encoding="utf-8")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=f, args=(8790,"/home/user/zim/wikipedia_en_all_novid_2018-05.zim",""))
    p2 = Process(target=f, args=(8791,"/home/user/zim/whatever.zim",""))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I need to add `ZIMServer("/home/user/zim/math.stackexchange.com_eng_all_2018-08.zim",  index_file="/home/user/zim/math.stackexchange.com_eng_all_2018-08.idx", port=7890, encoding="utf-8")` , do I need to add another `def f(port):
     ZIMServer("/home/user/zim/math.stackexchange.com_eng_all_2018-08.zim",  index_file="/home/user/zim/math.stackexchange.com_eng_all_2018-08.idx", port=8090, encoding="utf-8")` for `math.stackexchange.com `?

Comment: not really you can adapt the function and pass it as argument. Wait, i'll do it.

Comment: edited my answer, replace "whatever" by "/home/user/zim/math.stackexchange.com_eng_all_2018-08.zim"